# How can I change weights of multi layer perceptron in Spark Mllib?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, neural-network, apache-spark-mllib

I want to change or edit the weights of MLP in Spark. I can see the weights by using

```
print(fitted_model.weights)
```

but I can not change the weights by using

```
fitted_model.weights = new_weights
```

it gives "Attiribute error cant set attiribute" error.
How can I change the weights?

Comment: can I know more on your purpose? are you doing some thing like transfer learning?

Comment: to increase accuracy, i will try new methods.

Comment: because, if you already know the weight, you can use it in initial weights  while training. then you will get great results..